# Redirect to Request page in hwioauthbundle

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

Suppose I have a page http://example.com/page1

I have placed login with facebook link here.

And also on another page,page2, I have placed login link with facebook.

What I want is that after clicking login with facebook link on page1, it should redirect to page1 and on clicking login link on page2 , it should redirect to Page2.

Right now,it always redirect to 'example.com/'.

I am using Hwioauthbundle in integration with fosuserbundle in Symfony2

Comment: I had the same issue, right now I save the route to be redirected in a Session and use target_path option for hwi. So after the login is successful, you go to your default target which redirects to the proper link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Create an authentication handler

```
<?php

namespace Company\Bundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class SecurityHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{

    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        if (empty($referer)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
        } else {
            return new RedirectResponse($referer);
        }
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // Edit it to meet your requeriments
        $request->getSession()->set('login_error', $error);
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login_route'));
    }

}
```

2) Register it as service

```
# src/Company/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml
security_handler:
    class: Company\Bundle\Handler\SecurityHandler
    arguments:  [@router]
```

3) Config HWIO to use this service as handler

```
# app/config/security.yml
firewalls:
# ....
you_firewall:
    oauth:
        # ....
        resource_owners:
            # ....
        success_handler:    security_handler
        failure_handler:    security_handler # optional
```

Comment: Good work, but there is a one error: __contruct => __construct

Comment: Glad to help, fixed typo!

Comment: +1 for my comment? :P